# Excel VBA: problem passing workbook, worksheet objects to subroutines

Tags: excel, vba, object, parameters

I have a main routine that creates a new Workbook and dynamically associates new sheets with it (based on the data in a separate input workbook/sheet).

Excerpting the main routine:

```
Sub MainRoutine()
    Dim NmOutBook As String
    NmOutBook = "Client1Output_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")

    Dim PosSourceBk, TrnSourceBk, OutputBk As Workbook
    Set PosSourceBk = Workbooks.Open("U:\Documents\Implementations\Client1\Client1Positions.xlsx")
    Set TrnSourceBk = Workbooks.Open("U:\Documents\Implementations\Client1\TradeHistory_0301.xlsx")
    Dim TrnSrcSht, TrnOutSht, PriorTrnOutSht, PosOutSht As Worksheet
    Set TrnSrcSht = TrnSourceBk.ActiveSheet

    'Create workbook to store output sheets
    Set OutputBk = Workbooks.Add
```

...

```
If (SecNm <> PriorSecNm) Then
    Set TrnOutSht = OutputBk.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    TrnOutShtName = CStr(SecNm) + "_b"
    TrnOutSht.Name = TrnOutShtName
    AddXactSheetHeaders OutputBk, TrnOutSht
```

I'm passing my output workbook object and the corresponding worksheet object to the subroutine AddXactSheetHeaders, which looks like this:

```
Sub AddXactSheetHeaders(ByVal wb, ByVal ws)
    With wb
        With ws
            Range("A1").Value = "TradeDate"
            Range("B1").Value = "SettleDate"
            Range("C1").Value = "Tran ID"
            Range("D1").Value = "Tranx Type"
            Range("E1").Value = "Security Type"
            Range("F1").Value = "Security ID"
            Range("G1").Value = "SymbolDescription"
            Range("H1").Value = "Local Amount"
            Range("I1").Value = "Book Amount"
            Range("J1").Value = "MOIC Label"
            Range("K1").Value = "Quantity"
            Range("L1").Value = "Price"
            Range("M1").Value = "CurrencyCode"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The result of this is that cells A1:M1 are updated, but in the wrong workbook / worksheet.

I've tried passing the object references by reference; when I do this a different (but still wrong) workbook / worksheet is updated.

I must be missing something obvious, but have no idea what it might be.

Any assistance appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *ByRef* to pass the workbook/worksheet objects by pointer instead of copying them then use them as parent references in the helper sub. To reference a Range inside a With ... End With, use a prefix period.

```
Sub AddXactSheetHeaders(Byref wb as workbook, ByRef ws as worksheet)

  With wb
   With ws
     .Range("A1").Value = "TradeDate"
     .Range("B1").Value = "SettleDate"
     .Range("C1").Value = "Tran ID"
     .Range("D1").Value = "Tranx Type"
     .Range("E1").Value = "Security Type"
     .Range("F1").Value = "Security ID"
     .Range("G1").Value = "SymbolDescription"
     .Range("H1").Value = "Local Amount"
     .Range("I1").Value = "Book Amount"
     .Range("J1").Value = "MOIC Label"
     .Range("K1").Value = "Quantity"
     .Range("L1").Value = "Price"
     .Range("M1").Value = "CurrencyCode"
   End With
  End With 

End Sub
```

In fact, the *wb* reference is completely unnecessary and syntactically wrong. The *ws* worksheet knows what its parent workbook is.

```
Sub AddXactSheetHeaders(ByRef ws as worksheet)

  With ws
     .Range("A1").Value = "TradeDate"
     .Range("B1").Value = "SettleDate"
     .Range("C1").Value = "Tran ID"
     .Range("D1").Value = "Tranx Type"
     .Range("E1").Value = "Security Type"
     .Range("F1").Value = "Security ID"
     .Range("G1").Value = "SymbolDescription"
     .Range("H1").Value = "Local Amount"
     .Range("I1").Value = "Book Amount"
     .Range("J1").Value = "MOIC Label"
     .Range("K1").Value = "Quantity"
     .Range("L1").Value = "Price"
     .Range("M1").Value = "CurrencyCode"
  End With 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because inside your `With` Segment, you are not using a dot (.) to specify the change in that wb/ws.

Inside any `With` segments, using a dot, ties the "command" to the `With` Segment. Ej:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Range("A5").Value = "String Test" 'This changes the Cell A5 of the ActiveSheet
    .Range("A5").Value = "Test 2" 'This Changes the Value of Sheet5, part of the With Segment
End With
```

Just add the Dots/Periods

```
Sub AddXactSheetHeaders(ByVal wb, ByVal ws)
    With wb
        With ws
            .Range("A1").Value = "TradeDate"
            .Range("B1").Value = "SettleDate"
            .Range("C1").Value = "Tran ID"
            .Range("D1").Value = "Tranx Type"
            .Range("E1").Value = "Security Type"
            .Range("F1").Value = "Security ID"
            .Range("G1").Value = "SymbolDescription"
            .Range("H1").Value = "Local Amount"
            .Range("I1").Value = "Book Amount"
            .Range("J1").Value = "MOIC Label"
            .Range("K1").Value = "Quantity"
            .Range("L1").Value = "Price"
            .Range("M1").Value = "CurrencyCode"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks user11198948 and Ricardo A. A dot makes all the difference!